# How to compare goodness of fit of rqpd quantile model with plm

Tags: r, regression, quantile, non-linear-regression, quantile-regression

I work in R and have a large panel dataset: 10 variables, 5 time periods, and 10000 geographic units. I fitted a set of plm models (pooled, RE and FE) and noted that FE model failed as the adjusted R2 was negative. Given the nature of my data, I still believed that there could be some FE and fitted a rqpd 'pfe' model. The problem is that I do not see any measure of fit in its summary. How could I compare the goodness of fit of the quantile model with the standard approach?